# Ract-Native Android build failed - unable to find valid certification path to requested target

Tags: java, android, reactjs, facebook, react-native

I created sample react-native project using "react-native init HelloWorld". I am seeing following error continuously when I run "react-native run-android".  I tried with solutions provided for similar solution at these links. But it it didnt solve the problem.

[Post1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41460313/sun-security-provider-certpath-suncertpathbuilderexception-unable-to-find-valid)
[Post2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21076179/pkix-path-building-failed-and-unable-to-find-valid-certification-path-to-requ)

**Android Build.gradle in react native project:**

```js
// Top-level build file where you can add configuration options common to all sub-projects/modules.

buildscript {
    ext {
        buildToolsVersion = "27.0.3"
        minSdkVersion = 16
        compileSdkVersion = 27
        targetSdkVersion = 26
        supportLibVersion = "27.1.1"
    }
    repositories {
        jcenter()
        google()
    }
    dependencies {
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:3.1.4'

        // NOTE: Do not place your application dependencies here; they belong
        // in the individual module build.gradle files
    }
}

allprojects {
    repositories {
        mavenLocal()
        jcenter()
        maven {
            // All of React Native (JS, Obj-C sources, Android binaries) is installed from npm
            url "$rootDir/../node_modules/react-native/android"
        }
        google()
    }
}


task wrapper(type: Wrapper) {
    gradleVersion = '4.4'
    distributionUrl = distributionUrl.replace("bin", "all")
}
```

**gradle-wrapper.properties file in react-native project**

```js
distributionBase=GRADLE_USER_HOME
distributionPath=wrapper/dists
zipStoreBase=GRADLE_USER_HOME
zipStorePath=wrapper/dists
distributionUrl=http\://services.gradle.org/distributions/gradle-4.4-all.zip
```

**Error:**

```js
D:\My Projects\PULSE\Phase II\ReactNative\Projects\HellowWorld>react-native run-android
Starting JS server...
Building and installing the app on the device (cd android && gradlew.bat installDebug)...
FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

* What went wrong:
Could not resolve all files for configuration ':app:debugCompileClasspath'.
> Could not resolve com.facebook.infer.annotation:infer-annotation:0.11.2.
  Required by:
      project :app > com.facebook.react:react-native:0.57.0
   > Could not resolve com.facebook.infer.annotation:infer-annotation:0.11.2.
      > Could not get resource 'https://jcenter.bintray.com/com/facebook/infer/annotation/infer-annotation/0.11.2/infer-annotation-0.11.2.pom'.
         > Could not GET 'https://jcenter.bintray.com/com/facebook/infer/annotation/infer-annotation/0.11.2/infer-annotation-0.11.2.pom'.
            > sun.security.validator.ValidatorException: PKIX path building failed: sun.security.provider.certpath.SunCertPathBuilderException: unable to find valid certification path to requested target
   > Could not resolve com.facebook.infer.annotation:infer-annotation:0.11.2.
      > Could not get resource 'https://dl.google.com/dl/android/maven2/com/facebook/infer/annotation/infer-annotation/0.11.2/infer-annotation-0.11.2.pom'.
         > Could not GET 'https://dl.google.com/dl/android/maven2/com/facebook/infer/annotation/infer-annotation/0.11.2/infer-annotation-0.11.2.pom'.
            > sun.security.validator.ValidatorException: PKIX path building failed: sun.security.provider.certpath.SunCertPathBuilderException: unable to find valid certification path to requested target
> Could not resolve com.facebook.fresco:fresco:1.10.0.
  Required by:
      project :app > com.facebook.react:react-native:0.57.0
   > Could not resolve com.facebook.fresco:fresco:1.10.0.
      > Could not get resource 'https://jcenter.bintray.com/com/facebook/fresco/fresco/1.10.0/fresco-1.10.0.pom'.
         > Could not GET 'https://jcenter.bintray.com/com/facebook/fresco/fresco/1.10.0/fresco-1.10.0.pom'.
            > sun.security.validator.ValidatorException: PKIX path building failed: sun.security.provider.certpath.SunCertPathBuilderException: unable to find valid certification path to requested target
   > Could not resolve com.facebook.fresco:fresco:1.10.0.
      > Could not get resource 'https://dl.google.com/dl/android/maven2/com/facebook/fresco/fresco/1.10.0/fresco-1.10.0.pom'.
         > Could not GET 'https://dl.google.com/dl/android/maven2/com/facebook/fresco/fresco/1.10.0/fresco-1.10.0.pom'.
            > sun.security.validator.ValidatorException: PKIX path building failed: sun.security.provider.certpath.SunCertPathBuilderException: unable to find valid certification path to requested target
> Could not resolve com.facebook.fresco:imagepipeline-okhttp3:1.10.0.
  Required by:
      project :app > com.facebook.react:react-native:0.57.0
   > Could not resolve com.facebook.fresco:imagepipeline-okhttp3:1.10.0.
      > Could not get resource 'https://jcenter.bintray.com/com/facebook/fresco/imagepipeline-okhttp3/1.10.0/imagepipeline-okhttp3-1.10.0.pom'.
         > Could not GET 'https://jcenter.bintray.com/com/facebook/fresco/imagepipeline-okhttp3/1.10.0/imagepipeline-okhttp3-1.10.0.pom'.
            > sun.security.validator.ValidatorException: PKIX path building failed: sun.security.provider.certpath.SunCertPathBuilderException: unable to find valid certification path to requested target
   > Could not resolve com.facebook.fresco:imagepipeline-okhttp3:1.10.0.
      > Could not get resource 'https://dl.google.com/dl/android/maven2/com/facebook/fresco/imagepipeline-okhttp3/1.10.0/imagepipeline-okhttp3-1.10.0.pom'.
         > Could not GET 'https://dl.google.com/dl/android/maven2/com/facebook/fresco/imagepipeline-okhttp3/1.10.0/imagepipeline-okhttp3-1.10.0.pom'.
            > sun.security.validator.ValidatorException: PKIX path building failed: sun.security.provider.certpath.SunCertPathBuilderException: unable to find valid certification path to requested target
> Could not resolve com.facebook.soloader:soloader:0.5.1.
  Required by:
      project :app > com.facebook.react:react-native:0.57.0
   > Could not resolve com.facebook.soloader:soloader:0.5.1.
      > Could not get resource 'https://jcenter.bintray.com/com/facebook/soloader/soloader/0.5.1/soloader-0.5.1.pom'.
         > Could not GET 'https://jcenter.bintray.com/com/facebook/soloader/soloader/0.5.1/soloader-0.5.1.pom'.
            > sun.security.validator.ValidatorException: PKIX path building failed: sun.security.provider.certpath.SunCertPathBuilderException: unable to find valid certification path to requested target
   > Could not resolve com.facebook.soloader:soloader:0.5.1.
      > Could not get resource 'https://dl.google.com/dl/android/maven2/com/facebook/soloader/soloader/0.5.1/soloader-0.5.1.pom'.
         > Could not GET 'https://dl.google.com/dl/android/maven2/com/facebook/soloader/soloader/0.5.1/soloader-0.5.1.pom'.
            > sun.security.validator.ValidatorException: PKIX path building failed: sun.security.provider.certpath.SunCertPathBuilderException: unable to find valid certification path to requested target
> Could not resolve com.google.code.findbugs:jsr305:3.0.2.
  Required by:
      project :app > com.facebook.react:react-native:0.57.0
   > Could not resolve com.google.code.findbugs:jsr305:3.0.2.
      > Could not get resource 'https://jcenter.bintray.com/com/google/code/findbugs/jsr305/3.0.2/jsr305-3.0.2.pom'.
         > Could not GET 'https://jcenter.bintray.com/com/google/code/findbugs/jsr305/3.0.2/jsr305-3.0.2.pom'.
            > sun.security.validator.ValidatorException: PKIX path building failed: sun.security.provider.certpath.SunCertPathBuilderException: unable to find valid certification path to requested target
   > Could not resolve com.google.code.findbugs:jsr305:3.0.2.
      > Could not get resource 'https://dl.google.com/dl/android/maven2/com/google/code/findbugs/jsr305/3.0.2/jsr305-3.0.2.pom'.
         > Could not GET 'https://dl.google.com/dl/android/maven2/com/google/code/findbugs/jsr305/3.0.2/jsr305-3.0.2.pom'.
            > sun.security.validator.ValidatorException: PKIX path building failed: sun.security.provider.certpath.SunCertPathBuilderException: unable to find valid certification path to requested target
> Could not resolve com.squareup.okhttp3:okhttp:3.10.0.
  Required by:
      project :app > com.facebook.react:react-native:0.57.0
   > Could not resolve com.squareup.okhttp3:okhttp:3.10.0.
      > Could not get resource 'https://jcenter.bintray.com/com/squareup/okhttp3/okhttp/3.10.0/okhttp-3.10.0.pom'.
         > Could not HEAD 'https://jcenter.bintray.com/com/squareup/okhttp3/okhttp/3.10.0/okhttp-3.10.0.pom'.
            > sun.security.validator.ValidatorException: PKIX path building failed: sun.security.provider.certpath.SunCertPathBuilderException: unable to find valid certification path to requested target
   > Could not resolve com.squareup.okhttp3:okhttp:3.10.0.
      > Could not get resource 'https://dl.google.com/dl/android/maven2/com/squareup/okhttp3/okhttp/3.10.0/okhttp-3.10.0.pom'.
         > Could not HEAD 'https://dl.google.com/dl/android/maven2/com/squareup/okhttp3/okhttp/3.10.0/okhttp-3.10.0.pom'.
            > sun.security.validator.ValidatorException: PKIX path building failed: sun.security.provider.certpath.SunCertPathBuilderException: unable to find valid certification path to requested target
> Could not resolve com.squareup.okhttp3:okhttp-urlconnection:3.10.0.
  Required by:
      project :app > com.facebook.react:react-native:0.57.0
   > Could not resolve com.squareup.okhttp3:okhttp-urlconnection:3.10.0.
      > Could not get resource 'https://jcenter.bintray.com/com/squareup/okhttp3/okhttp-urlconnection/3.10.0/okhttp-urlconnection-3.10.0.pom'.
         > Could not HEAD 'https://jcenter.bintray.com/com/squareup/okhttp3/okhttp-urlconnection/3.10.0/okhttp-urlconnection-3.10.0.pom'.
            > sun.security.validator.ValidatorException: PKIX path building failed: sun.security.provider.certpath.SunCertPathBuilderException: unable to find valid certification path to requested target
   > Could not resolve com.squareup.okhttp3:okhttp-urlconnection:3.10.0.
      > Could not get resource 'https://dl.google.com/dl/android/maven2/com/squareup/okhttp3/okhttp-urlconnection/3.10.0/okhttp-urlconnection-3.10.0.pom'.
         > Could not HEAD 'https://dl.google.com/dl/android/maven2/com/squareup/okhttp3/okhttp-urlconnection/3.10.0/okhttp-urlconnection-3.10.0.pom'.
            > sun.security.validator.ValidatorException: PKIX path building failed: sun.security.provider.certpath.SunCertPathBuilderException: unable to find valid certification path to requested target
> Could not resolve com.squareup.okio:okio:1.14.0.
  Required by:
      project :app > com.facebook.react:react-native:0.57.0
   > Could not resolve com.squareup.okio:okio:1.14.0.
      > Could not get resource 'https://jcenter.bintray.com/com/squareup/okio/okio/1.14.0/okio-1.14.0.pom'.
         > Could not HEAD 'https://jcenter.bintray.com/com/squareup/okio/okio/1.14.0/okio-1.14.0.pom'.
            > sun.security.validator.ValidatorException: PKIX path building failed: sun.security.provider.certpath.SunCertPathBuilderException: unable to find valid certification path to requested target
   > Could not resolve com.squareup.okio:okio:1.14.0.
      > Could not get resource 'https://dl.google.com/dl/android/maven2/com/squareup/okio/okio/1.14.0/okio-1.14.0.pom'.
         > Could not HEAD 'https://dl.google.com/dl/android/maven2/com/squareup/okio/okio/1.14.0/okio-1.14.0.pom'.
            > sun.security.validator.ValidatorException: PKIX path building failed: sun.security.provider.certpath.SunCertPathBuilderException: unable to find valid certification path to requested target
> Could not resolve org.webkit:android-jsc:r174650.
  Required by:
      project :app > com.facebook.react:react-native:0.57.0
   > Could not resolve org.webkit:android-jsc:r174650.
      > Could not get resource 'https://jcenter.bintray.com/org/webkit/android-jsc/r174650/android-jsc-r174650.pom'.
         > Could not HEAD 'https://jcenter.bintray.com/org/webkit/android-jsc/r174650/android-jsc-r174650.pom'.
            > sun.security.validator.ValidatorException: PKIX path building failed: sun.security.provider.certpath.SunCertPathBuilderException: unable to find valid certification path to requested target
   > Could not resolve org.webkit:android-jsc:r174650.
      > Could not get resource 'https://dl.google.com/dl/android/maven2/org/webkit/android-jsc/r174650/android-jsc-r174650.pom'.
         > Could not HEAD 'https://dl.google.com/dl/android/maven2/org/webkit/android-jsc/r174650/android-jsc-r174650.pom'.
            > sun.security.validator.ValidatorException: PKIX path building failed: sun.security.provider.certpath.SunCertPathBuilderException: unable to find valid certification path to requested target

* Try:
Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace. Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output. Run with --scan to get full insights.

* Get more help at https://help.gradle.org

BUILD FAILED in 27s
1 actionable task: 1 executed
Could not install the app on the device, read the error above for details.
Make sure you have an Android emulator running or a device connected and have
set up your Android development environment:
https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/getting-started.html
```

**Following are the react-native versions I am using**
[image]

Answer (score 0):

Due to some reasons `"cacerts"` file corrupted - located at `"C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_181\jre\lib\security"` in my local PC. So I was able to resolve this issue after re-installing  `jdk1.8.0_181`.